# Dart Class 'String' has no instance method 'cast'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have written a dart method that takes a generic type T and then attempts to cast a dynamic type to T. (EDIT: I have since removed generics from the equation, and the cast from dynamic to String is still failing with the same error.)

In this specific scenario, I am passing a String as T.

The following line throws the error

```
 T result = value.cast<T>();
```

The complete code is as follows...

```
class JsonObject{
    final Map<String, dynamic> _map;
    JsonObject(this._map);

    T getValue<T>(String key) {
        dynamic value = _map[key];
        if (value == null)
            throw new JsonParseException._("JsonMap: can not find value with key = "+key);
        T result = value.cast<T>();
        if (result == null)
            throw new JsonParseException._("JsonMap: value with key = "+key+" is not of requested type "+T.toString());
        return result;
    }

    String getString(String key) => getValue<String>(key);
}
```

The error I am getting is as follows. I have trimmed the stack trace after the first call into my application code.

> 06-25 09:34:04.883 I/flutter ( 7755): Class 'String' has no instance
>   method 'cast'. 06-25 09:34:04.883 I/flutter ( 7755): Receiver: "foo1"
>   06-25 09:34:04.883 I/flutter ( 7755): Tried calling: cast()
>   06-25 09:34:04.920 I/flutter ( 7755): When the exception was thrown,
>   this was the stack: 06-25 09:34:05.004 I/flutter ( 7755): #0
>   Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:50:5) 06-25
>   09:34:05.011 I/flutter ( 7755): #1      JsonObject.getValue
>   (package:my_app/Util/json_parser.dart:62:26)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cast` is a method on `List`s and `Iterable`s, not on general types. You are looking for `as`.

Replace `T result = value.cast<T>();` with `T result = value as T;`. This will throw if `value` isn't a `T`. Either live with that, or catch it and throw your `JsonParseException`.